# Java streams is throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-stream, collectors

I am a bit new to Java streams and struck in the following issue. I tried many things mentioned on this website and in the various articles but was unable to fix them so posting the question here.

I am creating a `Map<String, Object>` using the `JavaStreams` within my application and then I pass the value to the `Map` with duplicate `keys` then it throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key namespace:localName (attempted merging values [ONE] and [TWO])

    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:133)
```

Following is the method that's throwing this error:

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (complex != null && complex.size() > 0) {
        final Map<String, Object> complexMap = complex.stream()
                .flatMap(c -> c.toMap().entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        map.put(namespacePrefix.concat(":").concat(localName), complexMap);
    } else {
        map.put(namespacePrefix.concat(":").concat(localName), text);
    }
    return map;
}
```

I tried to make the `Object` as `List` so that if duplicate values are found then add it to the `List` something like this:

```
List<Object> values = (List<Object>) map.get(namespacePrefix.concat(":").concat(localName));
if (values == null) {
    values = new ArrayList<Object>();
}
values.add(text);
map.put(namespacePrefix.concat(":").concat(localName), values);
```

But this also does not seem to work for me. I want to retain both the values if the key is duplicates because I need all the values within my application. Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong here and some idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Aside: don't use `concat`, use `namespacePrefix + ":" + localName`.

Comment: Can you show what data `complex` contains, and what the expected result is?

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried without using `concat` still throws the same error.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 that's why I said "aside:"

Comment: @Sweeper `Complex` is `Null` actually I am getting the error in else part when i am trying to add `text` to `Map`.

Comment: You should not stop reading a stacktrace after the first line. I tells you precisely the relevant line of your source code, so you don’t have to perform trial and error with the unrelated lines.

Comment: @Holger Thanks a lot for your response. I am unable to follow what exactly you are indicating. Can you please let me know what should I do in order to fix the issue.

Comment: You posted only a single line of the stacktrace, i.e. `at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:133)` and obviously ignored the remaining lines. Look at the other lines of the exception’s stacktrace, you haven’t posted. They will tell you that the stream operation failed. Once you understood that, you’ll realize how much time you could have saved by not trying to change the unrelated code dealing with the outer `map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The duplicates are not allowed using [`Collectors.toMap(Function, Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) method:

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to `Object.equals(Object)`), an IllegalStateException is thrown.

Now it depends what output you prefer:

- **`Map<String, Object>`**

  You need to use [`Collectors.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with a merging function that decides, which value should be used when the same keys appear.

  > If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), the value mapping function is applied to each equal element, and the results are merged using the provided merging function.

  This solution requires knowing what to do with two or more duplicated keys.
- **`Map<String, List<Object>>`**

  You need to use a grouping collector [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) that groups all values by a key, i.e. former values appear in the `List` as value. If the former key was duplicated, the new `Map` would appear once and the `List` as a value would have multiple elements.

  > Returns a Collector implementing a "group by" operation on input elements of type T, grouping elements according to a classification function, and returning the results in a Map.

  This solution adds you an option to identify duplicated fields and decide later on what to do with such values.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problematic line:

```
final Map<String, Object> complexMap = complex.stream().flatMap(c -> c.toMap().entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

The error is telling you that at least some of the maps in `complex` have keys in common.

You either need to use `Collectors.groupingBy`, which yields a list of items per key:

```
final Map<String, List<Object>> complexMap = complex.stream().flatMap(c -> c.toMap().entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

or use [the overload of `Collectors.toMap` which takes a merging function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)), allowing you to specify how duplicated keys should be handled.